# gcloud list instances in managed group sorted by creation time

Tags: gcloud

I need to get the oldest instance from an instance group. I am using the following command:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed list-instances "instance-group-name" --region "us-central1" --format="value(NAME,ZONE,CREATION_TIMESTAMP)" --sort-by='~CREATION_TIMESTAMP'
```

But it seems --sort-by is not working or I am using it a bit wrong.

Could you please suggest the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably `creationTimestamp` not `CREATION_TIMESTAMP`.

See: [instances.list](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list) and the response [body](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list#response-body) for the underlying field names.

It's slightly confusing but `gcloud` requires you to use the (field|property) names of the underlying request|response types **not** the output names.

Another way to more readily determine this is to add `--format=yaml` or `--format=json` to `gcloud compute instances list` (or any `gcloud` command) to get an idea of what's being returned so that you can begin filtering and formatting it.